# Asp.net mvc ViewBag access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I want to access Asp.net Mvc's ViewBag object from other class library's class. Is it impossible or impossible to access?

I have tried to write `System.Web.Mvc.ViewBag` in other Class library's class but ViewBag hasn't come after `System.Web.Mvc`

Comment: You can't access viewbag feature in class library.

Comment: anyways, what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using dto class for which fields isn't in my db model.I don't want to use dto classes  I want to achieve with ViewBag object to post

Comment: Could you give an example about ViewModel? How can i use ?

Comment: @user990513: Post your code over here.

Comment: It's too large and complex for paste here.

Comment: Not whole code, just the code snippet in which you're facing problem.

Comment: Actually i don't have problem with my code it works.For example one field isn't in in my model. But i want to add search screen. when i want to post this field i need a new model.So i am using new Dto object to post.But i have wanted to do this issue with ViewBag. I hope  i could say what i want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewBag persists within the life time of request.

So you can't use it in other class Library as it is available of the particular request.
It’s life lies only during the current request.

If redirection occurs then it’s value becomes null.

Here is well explained blog
http://www.rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications